# PL/SQL Anonymous block 'Exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows'

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've been working on a PL/SQL script that calculates the similarity between two recipes.
*Recipe* is the table containing all the titles, prep etc. *Ingredient* is where all the unique ingredients are stored, and *recipeing* is where the many to many problem is solved, and the two are linked.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_similarity
  (idS1 IN recipes.recipe.recipeID%type , idS2 IN recipes.recipe.recipeID%type ) 
  RETURN NUMBER 
AS 
sim_value NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
SELECT  2* 
    (select count(*) from recipes.ingredient i where i.ingredientID in (
      Select distinct ingredientID from recipes.recipeing where recipeID = s1.recipeID
      intersect
      select distinct ingredientID from recipes.recipeing  where recipeID = s2.recipeID))  
     /      ((select distinct count(ingredientID) from RECIPES.recipeing where recipeID = s1.recipeID) +
         (select distinct count(ingredientID) from recipes.recipeing where recipeID = s2.recipeID) )   INTO sim_value
from recipes.recipe s1, recipes.recipe s2
where s1.recipeID = idS1
and s2.recipeID = idS2;

RETURN (sim_value);
END func_similarity;
/
```

However, when I go to test it with an anonymous block, I get the error:
**"exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"**

```
declare
v_sim number;
begin
v_sim:=func_similarity(1,4);
dbms_output.put_line(v_sim);
end;
/
```

Now, I'm pretty sure the function makes sense and *should* work (took me all weekend). Does anyone have any ideas as to why this might not be working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u check query how amny row it return

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reason for geting ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067290/reason-for-geting-ora-01422-exact-fetch-returns-more-than-requested-number-of-r)

Answer (score 1):

There is no link between the two tables:

```
from recipes.recipe s1, recipes.recipe s2
where s1.recipeID = idS1
and s2.recipeID = idS2;
```

Consequently the query is a cross join.  This doesn't matter if `recipeID` is a primary key.  But if you have duplicate numbers in that column your query will return more than one row.  If your query returns more than one row your function will hurl a TOO_MANY_ROWS exception, because we can only select one row INTO a variable (unless we use BULK COLLECT INTO a collection variable
.

Comment: I've never used cross join before, but am I right in saying it returns the cartesian product of the sets of rows? Could you elaborate on how it could be used? In previous queries, inner join sufficed for linking the tables together with the 'linking' table - recipeing.

Comment: Please look at the bit of your code which I quoted. There is **NO** explicit join between those two tables (two instances of the same table). That produces an implicit cross join (which, yes, is a cartesian product).  I'm not suggesting you use CROSS JOIN, i'm saying you're already doing so, and that is what is causing the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

Only 1 line should be returned into sim_value. To see what is going on, run SQL without INTO and using values for IDS1 and IDS2.