# Using for loop i want to copy data from one table to another table in pl/sql code is under below

Tags: sql, plsql

this code is not working for me and message me and send a message

```
ORA-01422       exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
```

The code:

```
declare  
  a_id employees.employee_id%type;  
  b_name employees.first_name%type;  
  c_salary employees.salary%type;  
begin  
  for i in 1..10 loop  
    select employee_id, first_name, salary into a_id, b_name, c_salary from employees 
    where employee_id='a_id', first_name='b_name', salary='c_salary';  

    insert into awais(employee_id, first_name, salary) values (a_id, b_name, c_salary);  
  end loop;  
end;  
/
```

Comment: Welkome on SO! What did you do to find a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reason for geting ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067290/reason-for-geting-ora-01422-exact-fetch-returns-more-than-requested-number-of-r)

Comment: @awais salam: Can you explain what is the for loop (i=1..10) meant for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you could take a much simpler approach:

```
INSERT INTO awais
(SELECT employee_id, first_name, salary into a_id, b_name, c_salary
 FROM   employees 
 WHERE employee_id='a_id' AND first_name='b_name' AND salary='c_salary');
```

Comment: Dear sir i want to do this with for loop please it is possible

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your problem is that you are selecting more than one row into `a_id, b_name, c_salary`.

You can either use a direct `insert select`

```
INSERT INTO awais
SELECT employee_id, first_name, salary into a_id, b_name, c_salary
  FROM employees 
 WHERE employee_id='a_id' 
   AND first_name='b_name' 
    AND salary='c_salary';
```

Or you can user a cursor for loop:

```
declare  
  CURSOR c1
    IS
      select employee_id  a_id
           , first_name   b_name
           , salary       c_salary
        from employees 
       where employee_id='a_id' 
         AND first_name='b_name' 
         AND salary='c_salary'; 
begin  
  for i in 1..10 loop  
    for l_record in c1
    loop
      insert into awais(employee_id, first_name, salary) 
      values (l_record.a_id, l_record.b_name, l_record.c_salary); 
    end loop;


  end loop;  
end;  
/
```

Comment: your are awsome bro can I have to do this with for loop because i am learning this want to do this with for loop if possible then please tell me... bundle of thanks....